# What is the difference between Freeciv's classic and default ruleset?

Tags: freeciv

In Freeciv 2.5, there is a "classic" ruleset and a "default" ruleset. What is the difference between them? If not mistaken, there was no distinction between "classic" and "default" in Freeciv 2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form Freeciv wiki, [Classic ruleset](https://freeciv.fandom.com/wiki/Classic):

> Up to Freeciv 2.4 the classic ruleset was known as default ruleset.
> For Freeciv 3.x **civ2civ3 is expected to be the new default**.

Form Freeciv wiki, [Civ2civ3 ruleset](https://freeciv.fandom.com/wiki/Civ2civ3):

> Civ2civ3 is a ruleset shipped with Freeciv 2.5 and later. While it is a strikingly different game from Classic Freeciv, **it may be set as the "default rules" in some releases of Freeciv**.

From [2.5.0 changelog](https://freeciv.fandom.com/wiki/NEWS-2.5.0):

> civ2civ3 is planned to become the default ruleset in a future release. The current default ruleset has been renamed to 'classic' and will continue to be available. From now on the name 'default' will refer to whatever ruleset the running version of Freeciv defaults to.